# Programming Error : relation does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

```
ProgrammingError at /profile
relation "mtsauth_userinfo" does not exist
LINE 1: ...fo"."affliation", "mtsauth_userinfo"."phone" FROM "mtsauth_u...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://198.199.118.164/profile
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "mtsauth_userinfo" does not exist
LINE 1: ...fo"."affliation", "mtsauth_userinfo"."phone" FROM "mtsauth_u...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/django/django_project',
 '/home/django/django_project',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
```

I was clueless about this error. Dont know in which order `makemigrations` and `migrate` should be run for my project with postgresql in digitalocean.
So far I've been deleting migrations files and running those commands but not luck.

Is there anything which i need to know about makemigrations and migrate command on how they be run.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#workflow) explain how you use migrations. First you make the migration file with `makemigrations`, then you apply the migration with `migrate`. Deleting migration files that have already been applied is a bad idea, you end up with the database out of sync with your migration files. The easiest fix is to drop the database, delete the migration files, then start again. If you have important information in your database then you'll have to fix up the database/migrations manually, which is tricky.

Comment: @alasdair, how do i drop the databse in the server?

Comment: You can use `./manage.py dbshell` to open a database shell, then use the [drop database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-dropdatabase.html) command.

Comment: im getting error only owner can drop database,  but when i run `conninfo` it shows owner,which is my name,  is connected, i think i should connect to template1 database and delete this, problem is how to switch connection to different database

Comment: You can switch the connection to `template1` with `\c template1`. Then you should be able to delete the Django database.